# Why using os.system() won't mess up the stdout in python multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, operating-system

Recently I found an interesting result when playing around python multithreading. When using the code below, the stdout is really messy(definitely, since without using lock)

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
def printInt(x):
    print x*x

pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
args = [i for i in range(100)]
jobs = []
jobs += [job for job in pool.map(printInt, args) if job]
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Partial output:

```
31
32
3342
43


401344
```

But using os.system() with echo won't have this problem.

```
import os
def printInt(x):
    os.system("echo {0}".format(x))
```

Partial output:

```
58
59
60
61
62
34
77
```

Can anyone help to explain this from both python view and operating system  view? Thanks!

Comment: Try to set environment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 and then run your first script.